# Direct Wire LED: T12 Replacement

Tags: light-fixture, led, safety, fluorescent

## CONTEXT

An older office's 4-foot T12's are to be replaced with [direct wire LEDs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EMPH0QK) because the ballast cost + labor can be avoided.  The instructions indicate that the hot is wired to one end and the neutral is wired to the other end.  Because they are T12 fixtures, I believe they are non-shunted tombstones (sockets)

The new wiring configuration will be augmented with a sticker to indicate that only LED bulbs can be used and not to use T12 bulbs.

## QUESTION

If the sticker is ignored and a T12 is installed in the new wiring configuration: **120V AC applied to each end of the bulb**, will this result in a safety or fire hazard when the 120AC power is applied to the T12?

[image]

Comment: If you think that plugging in an old T12 tube is the only concern with this scheme, then beware that ["Among the 31 linear lamps tested in the aforementioned DOE Caliper report, seven different wiring configurations were used. Among the options, single- or double-ended wiring to the lamp, and shunted or non-shunted sockets are possible scenarios a retrofit installer might face."](http://www.ledsmagazine.com/articles/print/volume-11/issue-6/features/led-tubes/how-do-plug-and-play-t8s-stack-up-against-ballast-bypass-led-lamps.html)

Comment: For this question, each end of the LED is a single electric node: metal prongs on a given side are shorted.

Comment: @Fizz: please clarify (simplify) your comment: I think you have a good point to make, but it is not clear to me.  Thanks

Comment: My point is that if people/users ignore the written warning, they may plug in other kinds of tubes the fixture is not [re]designed for, including 4' T12 LED replacements that need a different wiring scheme.

Comment: @Fizz: understood and good point.  I have labeled the fixtures to communicate that only Direct Wired LED bulbs are to be used and that 120V AC is applied across the sockets.    Perhaps the best I can do is to keep a highly visible on-hand supply of the proper bulbs in the office to decrease the odds of an improper bulb selection+install.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A fluorescent light is an arc-discharge light (like neon, sodium, mercury vapor and metal halide).  There's a tube of gas and cathodes on each end.  It takes a high voltage to strike the arc, and a less-high voltage to sustain it.

4-foot T8 and T12 tubes have 2 pins on each end of the tube. They connect a small incandescent style filament, whose job is to preheat the cathodes to reduce the strike voltage and ease wear-and-tear on the tube.  Instant-start ballasts ignore this filament and use an extra high voltage to strike the arc.

Some LEDs want 120V on 2 pins on the same end, and the other end is a dummy.  On those, if you put a real fluorescent in there, you can expect a Pop! as the filament burns out.

Since you got the *powered on opposite ends* type of tube, I would expect nothing to happen.  The strike voltage of a 4' fluorescent tube is significantly  above 120V, especially without preheating.

Comment: There is no filament in a fluorescent tube. But it has a negative impedance, or more precisely "S" type

Comment: @Fizz not on 96" tubes, no.  However I am presuming OP is talking about common <=4' T12 fixtures, which certainly do, and they look like this.   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescent_lamp#/media/File%3ATanninglampend.jpg. Have you taken apart (read: broken, heh) any T12 tubes?

Comment: Yes, for this conversation: 4ft tubes

Comment: After checking the amazon link he gave he is indeed talking about those 4' preheat/bipin T12s.These "SHINE HAI" things say "Please note that in the case of ballast incompatibility a simple bypass of ballast may be require." Ahem. A preheat fluorescent tube will blow if used like that, with filament burning out and possibly loss of vacuum as well with a certain but small chance of mercury contamination of the environment. I'm not aware of fires, but who knows...

Comment: @fizz *These are not same-end-powered LEDs like the common ones you may be familiar with*.  These are dual-mode, that can work in plug-n-play OR ballast bypass.  Since they want to be compatible with instant-start ballasts, they draw hot and neutral from opposite ends. *Weird, huh?* Since they do, they do not need to worry about shorting vs non-shorting lampholders, or live vs. dummy ends.  Really, it's better all around.