# T8 retrofit with direct LED

Tags: light

[I have replaced 4-foot T12 fluorescent bulbs with direct wire LEDs](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/119039/direct-wire-led-t12-replacement): the fixtures were re-wired and ballasts removed to [accommodate the LEDs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EMPH0QK) .  In the future the LED bulbs can be replaced [unlike models that come with LEDs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K030M8C).  The goal is more to have reliable lighting and ease of repair when the light mechanism fails.  I also like the flexibility to change the bulbs if the light color needs to be changed.

A new [T8 4ft fixture](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Lithonia-Lighting-Cambridge-1-1-2-ft-x-4-ft-4-Light-Wood-Fluorescent-Ceiling-Fixture-3776RE/100135164) is to be installed in a kitchen.  I would like to continue using the same LEDs for this property so as to minimize on-hand spares.

As I understand it, [T8 sockets](https://www.atlantalightbulbs.com/blog/direct-wire-led-t8-tube-lights-and-what-you-need-to-know-about-sockets/) are non-shunted (suitable for single ended LEDs).  I would like to use dual ended LEDs (shunted sockets).  In practice, are non-shunted sockets shorted with a wire to convert them to shunted sockets?  Or is this not done for a safety \ economic \ practical reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dual-ended LEDs *do not require* shunted sockets.   The only restriction associated with LEDs and shunted sockets is that **same-end LEDs cannot be used on shunted sockets.**

Yes, if you have a non-shunted socket, you are entirely welcome to shunt it with a short piece of wire.  That is absolutely fine, in fact, if you look at the "yellow end" of a non-instant fixture, they are *already* shunting the yellow sockets *to each other*.  Note the wire is still insulated.

T8 sockets are available either shunted or non-shunted.  For us, who are not manufacturing fixtures in 50,000 quantity, we should avoid shunted sockets altogether. It takes seconds of our time to turn one into a shunted socket by adding a shunt wire.

The notion that "replaceable bulbs are better" is incorrect.  The experience in the computer industry is that socketing things makes them *less* reliable. There is no reason to make LED emitters socketed since they will outlive all of us, the problem is the supporting circuitry is often made cheaply.  Therefore a non-replaceable-element fixture of good quality will be much more reliable, on average, than a pair of commodity "manufactured to a price point" big-box store LED replacement tubes.

Of course you may take the "Google server farm" approach, and simply buy more cheaper things, let them fail, and just keep replacing parts.  I think for me, that would turn on how big a ladder I would need.